# While running maintenance run mode in UFT 12.02 gives error "Maintenance run mode is disabled"

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft, maintenance-mode

Please help me out if you'll might have had similar problem.
I am trying to run 'maintenance run' mode on 'Repository1.tsr' and i encounter the following error :

**"One of the resources associated with the test cannot be accessed by maintenance mode. Maintenance run mode is disabled."**

after this error, once i click on OK. the options of maintenance run mode are disabled.

Please see the screenshot for details. I have searched regarding this but didnot find the solution. 
[image]

I am trying hard to find a solution but have been unable to be even close.

Comment: Are you Sure you have only one Object repository associated with the test ? If u have multiple repositories see if u have write access to the file

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan - I have a local OR and another Repository1.TSR (this is the one I am targeting). Yes I have the write access to the file